# how to rerender a child component inside another component without controller ember

Tags: ember.js, components, render, ember-components, rerender

I have a parent component name-**card-mode**

```
**card-mode.js**
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
    card: null,
    previousPage: null,
    nextPage: null,
    init(){
        this._super(...arguments);

        if(this.get('errand').selectedMeasure != null){
            this.setCard("page/card/measure-master-summary");
        }
    },
    setCard(card){
        this.set('card', card);
    },
    actions: {
        setCard(name){
          this.setCard(name);
        },
        next(name){
            console.log(name);
            this.setCard(name);
        },
        previous(name){
            console.log(name);
            this.setCard(name);

        },
    }
});

**card-mode.hbs**
<div>
{{component card setCard=(action 'setCard') }}
</div>
<div>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary padding-lr" onclick={{action "previous" previousPage}}>previous<i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a> 
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary padding-lr npc" onclick={{action "next" nextPage}}>Next <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a> 
</div>
```

In this card mode component i will be rendering a component by calling setcard method.

Till this it works fine.

But now, i have to render a same child component multiple times in the parent component.

Think child-page-1, child-page-2 are two child components that should be rendered in parent component. child-page-1 and child-page-2 are rendered perfectly when am call them by using previous and next actions.

but when i try to call child-page-2 again call is not made to the child-page-2 init function again.

```
child-page-2.js

export default Ember.Component.extend({

    errand: Ember.inject.service(),
    selectedDimensionAnalysis: null,
    analysisTable:null,

    init(){
        this._super(...arguments);
        this.parentView.set('nextPage','child-page-1');
        this.parentView.set('previousPage','child-page-2');

        // results that will be displayed - 
        //results will be varied everytime based on the number of times it is called
    },
});
```

**My Question:**

how should i re-render the child component again. I am not using any controllers and model as i dont require them.

Answer (score 0):

You're assuming incorrectly that there is no controller.  If you dont define one Ember `generates` one for you.

If you install Ember Inspector you can see which controllers are present
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ember-inspector/bmdblncegkenkacieihfhpjfppoconhi?hl=en

[image]

**Suggestion:**

A component can be rendered multiple times if its added to a handlebar `HBS` file.  Instantiate a new component and pass in the properties you want it to consume from the parent.

sample `HBS`

```
{{child-page
        currentPage=3
        property1='something'
        property2='something'
}}
```